# Remove margins for some elements inside container

Tags: html, css

I want to remove space  (only right and left) between `.items` container and items, but to keep the margin between each `item`.

```css
.item {
  background-color: red;
  width:140px;
  height:180px;
  margin: 10px
}

.items {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:800px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to remove margin left and right between `.items` and the grid?

Comment: use CSS grid and the gap feature

Answer (score 1):

But the border on the outer container, and apply the negative amount of your `.item` margin, to the inner `.items` container.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 -10px; /* or just -10px, if you want to eliminate the
                      top/bottom ones as well */
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  width: 140px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove margin-left and margin-right, but save margin-top and margin-bottom, you can use following code:

```
.item {
  background-color: red;
  width:140px;
  height:180px;
  margin: 10px 0;  //First number is top and bottom, second is right and left
}
```